# Junit toString Partial coverage

Tags: java, junit, tostring

I was making a junit test fora  to string class here in net beans:

```
public String toString() {
        try {
            return "I am ContainerTruck " + getIdentifier() + ".\n\tI am at "
                    + getLocation() + " and am heading to " + getDestination()
                    + ".\n\tMy load is " + getCurrentLoadWeight() + " and my max load is "
                    + getMaxLoadWeight() + ".\n\tDistance to my destination is "
                    + String.format("%4.2f", distance(getDestination())) + ". "
                    + (atDestination() ? "I am there!" : "I'm not there yet");
        } catch (InvalidDataException ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

and netbeans keep saying I get partial coverage on my test:

```
public void testToString(){

                double lX = 1.0;
        double lY = 1.0;
        double lZ = 1.0;
        double dX = 1.0;
        double dY = 1.0;
        double dZ = 1.0;
        double spd = 1.0;
        double mxSpd = 1.0;
        double mlw = 1.0;
            try{
        ContainerTruck result = new ContainerTruck(lX, lY, lZ, dX, dY, dZ, spd, mxSpd, mlw);
                IdentifiableImpl imp = new IdentifiableImpl(result.getIdentifier());

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals("I am ContainerTruck " + imp.getIdentifier() + ".\n\tI am at [1.00, 1.00, 1.00] and am heading to [1.00, 1.00, 1.00].\n\tMy load is 0.0 and my max load is 1.0.\n\tDistance to my destination is 0.00. I am there!", result.toString());
        assertEquals(imp.getIdentifier(),result.getIdentifier());
        assertEquals(0.0, result.getCurrentLoadWeight(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getLocationZ(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getLocationY(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getLocationX(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getMaxLoadWeight(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getDestinationX(), delta);
        assertEquals(true, result.atDestination());
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getDestinationY(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getDestinationZ(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getSpeed(), delta);
        assertEquals(1.0, result.getMaxSpeed(), delta);
        }catch (InvalidDataException ex) {
            fail(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

can someone explain to me why this is still considered partial coverage?

Answer (score 2):

Your toString method is considering just happy scenario, where some of your method doesn't throw the exception and hence it never goes into catch block.

You should try calling the method in such a way that you get into catch block where you could return exception's message.

Comment: Ah Thank you!, I still think I'm having partial coverage issues though. Based off of netbeans the partial coverage is on the line of the string, which I don't understand why that is.